# How to automate google address suggestion bar with playwright

Tags: c#, automation, playwright-dotnet

Why is the google address suggestions not showing when automating using playwright or selenium. After typing in the google address bar the suggestions do not show. They only show when I assist manually ,that's the only time line 2 will execute.

```
//Line 1 is typing in the google address field
await Page1.Locator("input[name=\"ctl00\\$maincontent\\"]") .FillAsync("1026 Robertson Ave"); 

//Line 2 is selecting the option that will come up
await Page1.GetByText("Robertson").ClickAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with some other term where we can see dropdown , if i try **1026 Robertson Ave** , i only get avenue in the dropdown

so just to explain I have taken a different example which is working you can try running

```
[Test]
 public async Task PressSlowly()
{
 await Page.GotoAsync("https://google.com");
 await Page.Locator("//textarea[@class='gLFyf']").FillAsync("gaurav khurana");
 await Task.Delay(3000);
 await Page.GetByText("gaurav khurana linkedin").ClickAsync();
  await Task.Delay(10000);
 }
```

Also you can try slow filling to see how the data getting added using a timeout, so it fills slowly and you can see the options

```
 await Page.Locator("//textarea[@class='gLFyf']").FillAsync("gaurav khurana",new (){ Timeout= 3000});
```